# Disable button when the selected value in comboBox changed

Tags: c#

I have a button and a comboBox. The comboBox has 2 value, 'yes and no' I want to disable the button if the selected value is no while i want to enabled if the value selected is yes what would I do, I dont know where will I put the code and also my code seems wrong.

```
if (ComboBoxCustType.SelectedIndex = 0)
        {
            Button1.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
            Button1.Enabled = true;
```

Comment: Windows Forms or WPF?

Comment: You want your comparison to be `== 0`, not `= 0`.  If you turn it around it will never go wrong: `0 == ComboBoxCustType.SelectedIndex` because using the `==` instead of `=` is a compile time error.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't specify WinForms or WPF, this is for WinForms.

You have to create an event on the ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged and inside the event handler, you write your code to handle the selecteditem text.

```
public Form1()
{
  comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged;

  InitializeComponent();
  CheckSelction();
}

private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  CheckSelction();
}

void CheckSelction()
{
  if (comboBox1.SelectedItem != null)
  {
    var item = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    button1.Enabled = item == "yes";
  }
  else
    button1.Enabled = false;
}
```